# Alternative to a Query selector in JS - Internet Explorer 7 and Below

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, src

I'm trying to search for all elements on a page with a specific "src" value.   I have the following code in use for newer versions of IE/Chrome, but is not supported by IE7.

```
document.querySelector('[src="'+lname+'"]').parentElement.style.left=loffset;
```

The code for this app is auto generated, and these span/images do not have a global ID / Class associated.  (There is a word consistent in the ID, but I cannot do a wildcard search either in IE7.)

I have only been able to find something based on ID or class name... Is there a way to search specifically on src value of a page, on a specific element (Like span), or based on a wildcard ID search ?

Let me know if I can provide more info.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not use jQuery? It was specifically good back in the days of IE7 to solve exactly these sorts of problems.

Comment: Here is a polyfill https://gist.github.com/chrisjlee/8960575

Comment: I tried to create an alternative approach but sadly it will work with IE9+. https://textuploader.com/1oylp IE 7 is too old version and it is out of support. It is recommended to move to IE 11.

Comment: @VLAZ unfortunately, we cannot use that as the application is very old and would be too complicated.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out the other alternative commented, but we most likely will need to still support the older versions

Comment: I don't understand why jQuery can't be used. It *has been* historically with IE6 and others. Therefore even old applications could integrate it. The only real requirement here is to pick an older version of jQuery - you don't need the latest anyway.